# Disable log related to other application/system - android

Tags: android

I am using HTC One X.

There are some system application that has too many logs.

Because of that, I am able to see my application log only for some seconds. After some time, my logs are being remove from buffer since too many new logs from other application.

Can i disable log by using the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot stop other applications from logging! Probably some apps more than others log too extensively causing an overflow. What you could try to do is

> Force stop some apps so that thier logging activity is reduced(less chance it might reduce).

Secondly, as Rasel suggets,

> Use DDMS features like filtering logs using application name, package name, TAG's etc. and pause logging.

In this way you will get a snapshot of your logs. Hope this helps!

Comment: i cannot stop that application because that the system application. I have filtered the logs but the filtered logs are visible only for some seconds not enough for debugging.

Comment: Even i have a HTC One X but i have never seen such crazy logging, it might not be a system app thats logging so much. Is you Wifi/3G on too? I have seen some logging activity from them too. Whats the TAG/package name of the application that is logging so frequently.

Comment: The tags which are mostly found are LocSvc_eng, LocSvc_utils_q, LocSvc_utils_ll, LocSvc_adapter, LocSvc_api_v02. I found that all this are related to GPS (LocationManager). GPS is being used by my application

Comment: Aah! GPS, so disabling it reduces it? you are in a soup as those are system generated Logs and they cannot be stopped. The next best thing for you to do instead of logging using Log, Write to a txt file so that your messages are not missed. Will take a bit more coding but might solve your headache!

Comment: Good idea. I can disable the GPS. I can even export those logs from Logcat to txt. but can i again view that in logcat. or i can stop the logcat from getting more logs in eclipse.

Comment: Yes you can stop getting more logs, and also you can dump it into a text file at regular intervals. New updated SDK has a down arrow buttons that locks scrolling thus allowing you to browse through a snapshot.